# Удаление папки при старте тестов в Maven

Tags: maven, java

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - при запуске тестов нужно чистить папку в которой с прошлого запуска остались .log файлы прогнанных тестов, подскажите как такое реализовать в maven'е.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет [maven-clean-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html).

Comment: @Nofate, спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как в Maven, а в [Gradle](http://gradle.org) такое реализуется очень легко

Comment: нужно в maven (

Comment: очень жаль, я про maven давно забыл как про страшный сон, думаю нужно смотреть в сторону настройки test goal и плагина, позволяющего пользовать ant task в maven